# Asp.net Core File Upload With Ajax. How To Wait Block UI Till All Data Save To DB

Tags: excel, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, upload

I am using asp.net core MVC with $.ajax to upload. It is working fine. While uploading file I am using this $.blockUI(); to wait users till upload excel file to database. When the excel upload is successful, I use this to stop $.unblockUI(); but there is a problem. My code finishes before all data upload to database so that $.unblockUI(); is working but still data is keep going to save Database.

I want to wait ajax till all data save to Database. I want to solve this problem as I have been looking for it for all day but I haven't found anything to save me.

I tried to use thread but it doesn't good for me because the data can finis in 10 seconds or 2 seconds so that this is not good for me .

If you have any offer or example to solve my problem I would be very grateful.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you please post the details jquery codes and asp.net core codes you have used in your application? Without codes, we don't know why the $.unblockUI(); is working but still data is keep going to save Database.